# Read value from XML String using XPATH Java

Tags: java, xpath

I am looking to retrieve the value of Body element from XML. Though I've done the code right due to some reason I am getting NULL pointer exception.Any help is appreciated.

```
 package com.company;      
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
 import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
 import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
 import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.StringBufferInputStream;
 import java.io.StringReader;

 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args)  {

   String xmlDoc = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Body>This is my content</Body>";

  try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlDoc)));

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile("/Body");
    Node node = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println("Body: " + node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("Body").getNodeValue());           
       } 

  catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | DOMException | XPathExpressionException exp) 
  {
      exp.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
 String xmlDoc = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Body>This is my content</Body>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        String value = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlDoc.getBytes())))
                .getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
```

It returns value inside `<Body>` tag - "This is my content".

Answer (score 0):

Use `Node node = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE); System.out.println(node.getTextContent());`. But obviously you don't need XPath and can do `document.getDocumentElement().getTextContent()` directly. Also note that for XPath use in general a namespace aware document builder is recommended.

Comment: Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new                InputSource(new    StringReader(xmlDoc))); is statement returning NULL before hitting to document.getDocumentElement().getTextContent() step